# how to return data respone from axios

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

i have question, how to returning response data from axios in order to acessable when I call the function like bellow code

```
import react,{useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default function getAPI (v){
    var dataJson
    axios.post(v)
    .then((res)=>{
        dataJson =  res.data
    })
    console.log(dataJson)
    // how to return the json respone data in order can accessed by other function
    return dataJson
}
```

the script I wrotten, **dataJson** is undefined

Comment: axios is a Promise based http client.  So you will have to learn-up on javascript Promises to really get the full understanding how to not only use axios but to get the most out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await of Ecmascript 7 in this form to achieve this

You are exporting this function as default from this javascript file(example - test.js).

test.js

```
import react,{useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

export default async function getAPI (v) {
    const res = await axios.post(v);
    return res.data;
}
```

main.js

```
import getAPI from 'test.js';

async function execute() {
   const resposne = await getAPI();
   alert(resposne.status);
}

execute();
```

Wherever you are requiring/importing this file you will get this function as a reference which you will call and capture the API response returned from the function

Comment: how to call it function? so that I can alert the response code

Answer (score 0):

You can use async/await to achieve this easily.

```
export default async function getAPI (v){
  var res = await axios.post(v)

  console.log(res.data)
  return res.data
}
```

Alternatively you can pass a callback function which can be called from within the `then` section like below

```
export default function getAPI (v, callbackFn){
  axios.post(v)
    .then((res)=>{
      dataJson =  res.data
      console.log(dataJson) // this would print response
      callbackFn(dataJson)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are two methods you can do this:

1.) Using .then

```
import react,{useState} from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default function getAPI (v){
        axios.post(v)
        .then((res)=>{
         console.log(dataJson)
            return res.data
        })
    }
```

2.) Using try catch

```
import react,{useState} from 'react'
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default function getAPI async(v){
      try{
        const res = await axios.post(v);
        return res.data
      }
      catch (error){
       return error
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`dataJson` is undefined because you print it outside `then` function. Axios is async so `axios.post` and `console.log` will run same time.

You can use async/await to make it sync run or print `dataJson` in `then` function